# Joining data from JSON array object field with another table

Tags: postgresql, linq, linq-to-sql, npgsql, .net-core-3.1

Let say, I have two tables on Postgre database like below:

```
CREATE TABLE "MST"."Users" (
  "Id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  "Uid" varchar(32) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" NOT NULL,
  "Pid" varchar(100) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" NOT NULL,
  "Details" jsonb,
  "Contacts" jsonb,
  "Trackers" jsonb NOT NULL,
  "Configurations" jsonb,
  PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
  UNIQUE ("Uid")
);

CREATE TABLE "MST"."Teams" (
  "Id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  "Details" jsonb NOT NULL,
  "Members" jsonb,
  "Trackers" jsonb NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
```

which both tables mapped with the following models:

```
    [Table("Users", Schema = "MST")]
    public partial class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [StringLength(32)]
        public string Uid { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Pid { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public UserDetailsModel Details { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public UserContactsModel Contacts { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public TrackersModel Trackers { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public UserConfigurationsModel Configurations { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Teams", Schema = "MST")]
    public partial class Teams
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public TeamDetailsModel Details { get; set; }
        
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public List<TeamMembersModel> Members { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public TrackersModel Trackers { get; set; }
    }

    // Childs classes
    public class TeamMembersModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = @"Member ""User ID"" is required and can not be empty.")]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 32, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = @"Member ""User ID"" length must be between 3 and 32 chars.")]
        public string Uid { get; set; }

        public bool IsLead { get; set; } = false;

        public UserDetailsModel Details { get; set; }
    }

    public UserContactModel { 
        ...some properties...
    }

    public TrackersModel { 
        ...some properties...
    }

    public UserDetailsModel { 
        ...some properties...
    }
```

And below is data samples from **Teams** table:

```
INSERT INTO "MST"."Teams"("Id", "Details", "Members", "Trackers") VALUES ('daf0e3d3-78bf-443b-8b0b-6f74d2eabd7f', '{"Name": "My First Team", "Files": [], "Notes": null, "Photo": null}', '[{"Uid": "fadhly.permata", "IsLead": true}, {"Uid": "humaira.permata", "IsLead": false}]', '{"Status": "RG", "Created": {"At": "2020-08-14T12:15:59.4175028+00:00", "By": "SYSTEM"}, "Updated": null}');

INSERT INTO "MST"."Teams"("Id", "Details", "Members", "Trackers") VALUES ('538f1d58-01cb-4120-b89a-ea25bfacaa25', '{"Name": "My Second Team", "Files": [], "Notes": null, "Photo": null}', '[{"Uid": "fadhly.permata", "IsLead": true, "Details": null}]', '{"Status": "RG", "Created": {"At": "2020-08-19T10:51:44.5128139+00:00", "By": "fadhly.permata"}, "Updated": null}');
```

As you can see on my DB data, **Members** field is stored with an array of JSON. I am confused about how to join Teams->Members->Details with details from the Users table.

And this is my query:

```
from
    team in _manager.DbContext.Teams

where
    team.Trackers.Status != "DE"

orderby
    team.Details.Name

select
    new Models.Teams
    {
        Id = team.Id,
        Details = team.Details,
        Trackers = team.Trackers,
        Members = team.Members.Select(
            x => new TeamMembersModel { 
                Uid = x.Uid, 
                IsLead = x.IsLead, 
                Details = _manager.DbContext.Users.First(y => y.Uid == x.Uid).Details 
            }
        )
            .ToList()
    };
```

But I've no luck with the above query, and got this error message:
`"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

Perhaps, I was missing something, but unsure where is it.

---

**Note:**
I am using [NPGSQL](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html) as an additional/extension of EF engine, as I have added on this question tags too.

Comment: LINQ to SQL/EF doesn't have support for JSON fields. You will probably need to use a stored procedure or other custom SQL instead.

Comment: @NetMage Thanks for your response bro. At first, I thought like you. But after hearing JSON technology on DB, I try to deep-digging my knowledge about it. And I found [this](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco). With this engine, we can manage JSON easily. I have no problem with another table, but now I am stuck with an Array of JSON when I want to take the details from another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your projection of `team.Members`, which is a JSON property rather than an EF navigation - this cannot be translated to SQL for processing in PostgreSQL. As this is the final projection, this should simply get client-evaluated, but EF seems to have a bug around this (opened https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22161 to track).

If the intent is to get this to client-evaluate, simply place an AsEnumerable before the projection - this should make the error go away. Otherwise,

In theory, this could be done by translating the JSON array projection to `json_array_elements` ([see PG docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)), but it's extremely unlikely the provider will be able to do that any time soon.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. And thanks for your response. This is my first experience using JSON on DB. I am so lazy to read the docs, and just thinking the NPGSQL will be able to take the "details". So, I've know the truth after debugging and testing several days (LOL). The main focus is, I want to filter the data based on "details" values. Since my structure can not be fetched properly, then I have changed my DB structure to fulfill my need.